# for loop craziness

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, ios7

OK. I am going crazy here. I have a for loop that isn't stopping when it should.

I'm creating a dice game and the number of dice changes frequently so I just have a for loop generating the dice based on however many dice there should be at any given roll. Here is the loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < numDice; x++) {
    int dieNum = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
    SKSpriteNode *die;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        die = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dice-%i", dieNum]];
    } else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        die = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dice-%i_ipad", dieNum]];
    }

    die.name = @"die";
    die.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"Rollable"];
    [die.userData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dieNum] forKey:@"Die Number"];
    [die.userData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", rollNum] forKey:@"Roll Number"];
    [die.userData setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"Movable"];
    die.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:die.size];
    die.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    die.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = dieCategory;
    die.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = dieCategory;

    int rotation = (arc4random() % 360) + 1;
    die.zRotation = radians(rotation);
    int x = (arc4random() % (int)self.frame.size.width) + (die.size.width / sinf(90.0));
    int y = (arc4random() % (int)self.frame.size.height) + (die.size.height / sinf(90.0));
    if (x < 1.75 * (die.size.width / sinf(90.0))) {
        x = 1.75 * (die.size.width / sinf(90.0));
    }
    if (y < (die.size.height / sinf(90.0))) {
        y = (die.size.height / sinf(90.0));
    }
    if (x > self.frame.size.width - (die.size.width / sinf(90.0))) {
        x = self.frame.size.width - (die.size.width / sinf(90.0));
    }
    if (y > self.frame.size.height - (die.size.height / sinf(90.0))) {
        y = self.frame.size.height - (die.size.height / sinf(90.0));
    }
    die.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
    [self addChild:die];
}
```

Now I have an NSLog outputting the numDice variable just before the loop is executed and the numDice variable has been correct in every single one of my tests. For some reason though, the for loop was generating a random number of extra dice during a certain test. So i put an NSLog outputting the x value and saw something interesting. After the loop the log would say something like this:

```
2013-12-04 19:50:03.334 DiceMania[21611:60b] numDice: 6
2013-12-04 19:50:03.338 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 0
2013-12-04 19:50:03.338 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 1
2013-12-04 19:50:03.341 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 2
2013-12-04 19:50:03.346 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 3
2013-12-04 19:50:03.350 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 4
2013-12-04 19:50:03.352 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 5
2013-12-04 19:50:03.359 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 0
2013-12-04 19:50:03.363 DiceMania[21611:60b] x: 1
```

Why on earth is the loop resetting x to 0 and then doing a random number more iterations?? (I have noticed that x has gone anywhere from 1 to 6 iterations past what it was supposed to.

Comment: You are redefining x as a random number. You shouldn't assign to your loop counter. You need to rename its counter.

Comment: `int x = (arc4random() % (int)self.frame.size.width) + (die.size.width / sinf(90.0));` (not to mention reassigning it two other times after this) is problematic given `x` is your loop counter also.  A variable name as terse as `x` is fine as a loop counter.  It's really unacceptable for the name of any other variable.  You should use far more descriptive variable names... especially considering absolutely zero comments.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I didn't notice that. Now I feel stupid. Thank you all

Comment: After changing variable names the loop is still doing the exact same thing.

Comment: I even just hard coded the number of dice to roll and wrote an if statement to `break;` out of the loop once it's iterated through the loop that number of times and it still goes past what I set..

Comment: A good argument for not using `x` as a loop index.  Use a meaningful name for the loop index of a large loop.  And avoid using `x` for anything -- leave it in FORTRAN where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating the loop with `x` and also using it for the meat of the loop.  Split up the variables so they don't interfere with each other, and you should be fine.